# Why does flushing the stream has no effect, but flushing the writer has

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have the simplest client-server communication.

Client:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 12345);
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println(r.readLine());
    s.close();
}
```

Server:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(12345);
    Socket client = server.accept();
    OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(out));
    w.write("Hello client\n");
    w.flush(); //Works fine, client printed Hello client
}
```

But If we flush the stream an exception'll be thrown.

Server:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(12345);
    Socket client = server.accept();
    OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(out));
    w.write("Hello client\n");
    out.flush(); //Has no effect, doesn't deliver the line to the client.
}
```

What's the reason of that difference?

Comment: One part of your question says flushing causes an exception, but another part of your question says it has no effect. Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `BufferedWriter` adds a layer of its own buffering on top of the stream it is wrapping, independently.

When you flush the underlying stream, that's all you're doing. The `BufferedWriter` still has its buffers. You bypass those.

When you flush the `BufferedWriter`, however, you take care of its additional layer of buffering, sending those out to the underlying stream. The `BufferedWriter` implementation of `flush()` also calls `flush()` on the underlying stream afterwards, so you get a full chain of [ flush higher level buffers to underlying stream ] => [ flush the underlying stream ].

You can see that behavior in the [source for `BufferedWriter#flush()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/BufferedWriter.java#BufferedWriter.flush%28%29) (comments mine):

```
public void flush() throws IOException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        flushBuffer();   // Flushes this BufferedWriters buffers to 'out'.
        out.flush();     // Now flushes 'out' (the stream it wraps).
    }
}
```

If you call the underlying stream's `flush()` directly, essentially you are skipping that `BufferedWriter#flushBuffer()` call in the above code snippet.

Comment: Interesting, that's if we flush the top level buffer, the lower level will flushes automatically, right?

Comment: @St.Antario Yeah; sorry. I realized I forgot that detail and actually added it in right when you posted that.

Comment: The [Writer.flush() documetation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#flush()) may also be useful: "Flushes the stream. If the stream has saved any characters from the various write() methods in a buffer, write them immediately to their intended destination. Then, if that destination is another character or byte stream, flush it. Thus one flush() invocation will flush all the buffers in a chain of Writers and OutputStreams."

Answer (score 0):

The OutputStream API may help.

Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be written out. The general contract of flush is that calling it is an indication that, if any bytes previously written have been buffered by the implementation of the output stream, such bytes should immediately be written to their intended destination. 
If the intended destination of this stream is an abstraction provided by the underlying operating system, for example a file, then flushing the stream guarantees only that bytes previously written to the stream are passed to the operating system for writing; it does not guarantee that they are actually written to a physical device such as a disk drive.

**The flush method of OutputStream does nothing.**

and client.getOutputStream() get the SocketOutputStream which extends FileOutputStream and not override the flush mothod.

Comment: 1. `OutputStream#flush()` certainly does something: It guarantees that, after it is called, any internally buffered data has been passed to the OS for writing, which that documentation clearly states. 2. `SocketOutputStream` does override `flush()` -- it just does nothing, because it doesn't need to, because `write()` does all the necessary work for sockets (`SocketOutputStream` does no extra buffering). Therefore it still sticks to the `OutputStream` invariants described in that documentation. In any case, it doesn't matter what `SocketOutputStream` does, that's not the issue being observed.

Comment: 1.I agree with the point one.2 SocketOutputStream doesn't override flush() as it extends FileOutputStream which extends from OutputStream also doesn't override the flush mothod.And in OutputStream the flush mothod just like that:  public void flush() throws IOException {
    }

Comment: Yeah; sorry, it doesn't; but the rest of #2 holds. `SocketOutputStream#flush()` doesn't *need* to do anything (it still doesn't violate any of the stated rules), and it's not part of the issue the OP is describing. Note the OP's observations would be the same for *any* underlying stream type combined with a `BufferedWriter`; it doesn't matter that it's a `SocketOutputStream`.